Change Animation Direction On Click and Make Tab Content Responsive
How would I go about having the on click tab reveal from left to right only so it looks like it is popping out of the red bar (like a swiss army knife reveal)?
Right now it goes from right to left when you click each button and then reverses if you click a previous button.
I also noticed it is not responsive and doesn't fit the screen on mobile. What changes should I make to fix this as well?
Thank you in advance!

https://codepen.io/sadive/pen/QWPWMLG add the code here itself,edit it
